# React dead code elimination not performed on Meteor deployment using MontiAPM's recommended minify-js-sourcemaps

Tags: reactjs, meteor, minify, meteor-react

My MontiAPM subscription is detecting that dead code elimination is not being performed on my production deployment and I suspect that minify-js-sourcemaps might be the problem.

Here is the link to the MontiAPM error:
https://app.montiapm.com/et/8bf36546-da75-4a3b-9c00-2b0b168e619e/svZHraoAqMKmQcpkm

In investigating the error, I found this closed issue for Meteor, indicating it was fixed in the default release of minifier-js:
meteor/meteor#9260

However, in accordance with recommendations for MontiAPM, my project is using (the latest release of) minify-js-sourcemaps instead of minifier-js:
https://github.com/radgrad/radgrad2/blob/master/app/.meteor/versions#L110-L114

I request guidance on how to diagnose/resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had debug: true in the buildOptions field of my mup.js file.  Setting debug: false allowed the code to be minified and thus solved the issue.

Thank you to the Meteor Up team for helping me solve this problem.